# How to filter list of lists of different lengths

Tags: python

I have a list of lists:

```
first_list = [[grass], [grass], [grass, woodland], [grass, woodland, deer], [grass, deer], [grass, woodland]]
```

and I want to filter out those lists that contain class "woodland" anywhere in them, so that I have a new list of lists:

```
new_list = [[grass], [grass], [grass, deer]]
```

What is the best way to do this? Here's what I've tried, I think it hasn't worked because the lists within the list are of different lengths:

```
no_woodland_alone = [obj for obj in first_list if not isinstance(obj, woodland)]
```

Comment: Is `woodland` supposed to be an instance, a class, or a string?

Comment: Sorry, it's a class

Comment: `no_woodland_alone = [[o for o in obj if not isinstance(o, woodland)] for obj in first_list]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `isinstance(woodland, woodland)` is true in the first place, the problem is that you are checking the list, not its members.

```py
no_woodland_alone = [obj for obj in first_list if not any(isinstance(x, woodland) for x in obj)]
```

If it isn't true, probably you simply mean

```py
no_woodland_alone = [obj for obj in first_list if not any(x == woodland for x in obj)]
```

Mutatis mutandis if there is a different way to check whether a member should be selected or not.  This one works for me when I do `class woodland: pass`, `class grass: pass` etc and assign your `first_list` to what you say it contains.

(In case it's not obvious, `isinstance(woodland(), woodland)` is `True`; `isinstance(woodland, woodland)` is not.)

Answer (score 0):

```
first_list = [[grass], [grass], [grass, woodland], [grass, woodland, deer], [grass, deer], [grass, woodland]]

new_list = []

for i in first_list:
if (woodland in i):
    continue
else:
    new_list.append(i)
```